# AngularJS Error: [$injector:modulerr] came out of nowhere

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-maps, mean-stack

I was following a tutorial for creating a MEAN stack project with Google Maps integration. I finished the project without any problems, thus, I stopped working on it. When I came back to check on it, it just doesn't work anymore. I didn't change anything with the code. I even pulled a previously working commit from my repository but the error

```
[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=scotchApp&p1=Error…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387)
```

is still there. I really don;t have an idea what went wrong because this was previously working fine. I hope someone could help.

EDIT. Here's a part of the 'gservice' service of my project.

```
 // Creates the gservice factory.
// This will be the primary means by which we interact with Google Maps
 angular.module('gservice', [])
     .factory('gservice', function($rootScope, $http) {
```

Comment: post the code  here

Comment: Usually, that kind of error in AngularJS is caused by source minification or uglification. Are you using webpack, gulp, or Rails with it?

Comment: @IzumiSy, no I'm not. :)

Comment: mainController looks to lack a DI of `aservice`

Comment: I checked, and it's there. :)

Comment: Use the non-minified angularjs for debugging purposes. The error messages will also be more descriptive

Comment: Can you tell me how to use that?

Comment: instead of including `angular.min.js`, include `angular.js`

Comment: The last several controllers you have, don't have $scope injected.

Comment: @devqon, I did that and it gave me a more descriptive error which was: 
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module scotchApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module controllerStoreDetail due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module gservice due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'gservice' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I think you laid a dependency on your service instead of registering it, e.g. you did `angular.module("scotchApp", ["gservice"])` instead of `angular.module("scotchApp", []).service("gservice", ...)`

Comment: I think your file where the factory was either not declared in `index.html` or it got missing if the name was changed. please check once and check in source if it is loaded?

Comment: @Sravan, I checked and I did include it in the index.html. It's also loaded in the source.

Comment: @cryoheart but is it loaded **before** the main module declaration?

Comment: @devqon can you explain how that is done?

Comment: Is your js file which declares the `gservice` module included **before** the js file which declares the `scotchApp` module?

Comment: @devqon Yes it is. I really find this case weird as it was really working perfectly for weeks until now.

Comment: Is there a way we can access your project / see the error?

Comment: @VivekAthalye here's my repo. https://github.com/dynamicjpalmazan/mean-geolocation.git

Comment: Downvoting for not paying *enough* attention to @devqon's question

Comment: @VivekAthalye I actually did pay enough attention. I did what he told me.. I just did not push the changes to the repo. The error is still there.

Comment: Have you checked that your changes are getting reflected in your live system? Have you tried deleting cache and reloading the page?

Comment: I did try that. But it's still not solving the problem. I strongly believe that the problem is with the gservice file as only the modules that are dependent on it are acting up. If i try removing the dependency on the service, the project loads properly, only without the google maps functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: [components.html](https://github.com/dynamicjpalmazan/mean-geolocation/blob/master/public/component/components.html#L37-L39)

```
<!-- Client Scripts -->
<script src="../app/client/routes/script.js"></script>
<script src="../app/client/service/gservice.js"></script>
<script src="../app/client/service/aservice.js"></script>
```

Your `scotchApp` module is defined in `script.js` as:

```
 var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute',
     'ngCookies',
     'controllerStoreDetail', 'controllerStoreCategory',
     'controllerStoreQuery', 'controllerUserDetail',
     'controllerUserAuthentication', 'geolocation',
     'gservice', 'aservice',
     'datatables'
 ]);
```

It has a dependency on `gservice`, `aservice` etc. But those files are loaded after `script.js`. So while loading your module (`script.js`), angular is not able to find definition for those services. You need to make sure that all dependencies are loaded before `script.js`.

@devqon had asked this question:

> Is your js file which declares the gservice module included **before** the
>   js file which declares the scotchApp module?

To which you answered:

> @devqon Yes it is. I really find this case weird as it was really working perfectly for weeks until now.

Which doesn't seem to be the case.

Rectify the sequence in which you are loading JS files and the error will be gone.

Comment: The error is still there. I've done what you've said, I just didn't push the changes to the repo.

Comment: In that case I guess people will really need to *see* the error happening on your site, so that they can debug and help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can run the project from the repository I gave you.

Comment: Looking at the repository this is indeed a logical explanation of your error

Comment: @cryoheart 1.I don't have NodeJS environment. 2.Expecting others to setup the app with ur code base to solve ur problem is too much,IMHO. 3.If you have 1 uncommitted change,there could be more.No one will want to debug the code thats not guaranteed to be the one causing the issue. 4.Google services usually have limits & quotas on how many requests you can send.Some of these limits may depend on originating server too.So even if someone sets up their own environment with up-to-date codebase they *may not* get the error you are getting.Thats the reason I asked to **see the error** in first place

Comment: @Vivek Athalye, I understand where you're coming from. You asked to see the error that's why I said you can get the project from the repo. I wasn't asking you to do it for me. I already posted the error so I really don't get what you meant by 'see' so I took it as you wanting to run the project yourself. I appreciate your help but I already solved my problem and none of your suggestions were the solution.

Comment: Ok. Great. In that case I'll remove my downvote. Right now I'm not able to do it because its giving me an error "You last voted on this question 8 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited". So can you edit it? May be just add a tag `google-maps`; after all that's what was causing the problem.

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The cause was a missing 'v=3' in the src of the script for loading the Google Maps API. I still don't why that's the case as the project was previously working properly.